# How do I uninstall Dropbox?

Tags: uninstall, dropbox

After booting up, a popup screen tells me Dropbox did not install correctly, but it is lurking somewhere. To install properly I first have to delete the incorrect install. How can I do that?

I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 70):

This is from [Dropbox help page](https://www.dropbox.com/help/41/en):

```
dropbox stop
dropbox status  # Should report "not running"
rm -rf ~/.dropbox-dist
rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox
rm -rf ~/.dropbox*
sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox
sudo apt-get remove dropbox
rm /etc/apt/source.d/dropbox
```

Comment: `Package 'dropbox' is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: Unexpectedly, the commands listed here deleted Dropbox folders "in the cloud". i.e., I have Dropbox working well under different OSs, but running these commands deleted folders completely (rather than just from the current OS).
I tried performing this on linux, but notice the result from Mac.

Comment: as of August 2020, after running the `sudo apt-get remove` commands I also get the message `Package 'dropbox' is not installed, so not removed`; but if I type `dropbox` I get the `Dropbox command-line interface` and a list of commands to use.

Comment: As of June '22, I did this on Ubuntu 20.04. After running `sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox`, everything seemed to be done. When I ran `sudo apt-get remove dropbox` I saw `Reading package lists... Done // Building dependency tree // Reading state information... Done // Package 'dropbox' is not installed, so not removed`, and when I ran `rm /etc/apt/source.d/dropbox`, I saw `rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/source.d/dropbox': No such file or directory`

Comment: I found something in /home/.var/app that had to be removed to completely remove dropbox.

Answer (score 31):

Try this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nautilus-dropbox
```

Comment: Don't forget `rm -rvf ~/.dropbox ~/.dropbox-dist; rm -rv ~/Dropbox` to remove all settings made and the last Dropbox folder.

Answer (score 11):

Based on [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/41) you can follow this steps:

```
dropbox stop
dropbox status  # Should report "not running"

rm -rf ~/.dropbox-dist
rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox
rm -rf ~/.dropbox*
sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox
sudo apt-get remove dropbox
rm /etc/apt/source.d/dropbox
```

And if you want to delete the files that were synced, you can run this command:

```
rm -rv ~/Dropbox
```

Answer (score 4):

You can remove a package through `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get remove dropbox
```

Answer (score 2):

It works like this:

1. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to before the download of Dropbox tries to do anything.
3. Remove dropbox with `sudo apt-get purge nautilus-dropbox`

Comment: why would this work better than just running `sudo apt-get purge nautilus-dropbox`?

Comment: because once the package is broken you can not use apt/dpkg for nothing other than fixing the package... in my case it still throw sudo apt-get remove --purge nautilus-dropbox

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, because my internet fails

I did this:

```
sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

sudo rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Those were directories that were causing troubles

Then i just remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox
```

Pd.- After that I tried to install it again and it works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I ran all the above commands without any results. I was not able to uninstall no matter what so instead I ran with sudo apt install nautilus-dropbox and it installed all over again and at last I was able to launch and enter.