# Cannot remove Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

I tried to install Dropbox using Ubuntu Software centre but it stopped at some point

Now I cannot remove the partial installation. If I try using the Software centre it hangs.

At terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove dropbox
```

I get

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

What can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I uninstall Dropbox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182416/how-do-i-uninstall-dropbox)

Comment: @karel I don't think so... This is dealing with an error.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat The question was "cannot remove Dropbox". Obviously I can't cover both possibilities, but that's what I'm trying to do. Some of the question is obviously a duplicate, but if user3070181 accepts a different answer I'm going to retract my close vote to resolve the conflict. The issue is further complicated by the fact the if the Software Center is hanging because of a lock on dpkg, then your `sudo dpkg --configure -a` answer wouldn't work and he will have to uninstall Dropbox anyway.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat This problem is built like a house of cards, but it's possible to get some logic out of it. 1. How do I uninstall Dropbox? 2. Why does the Software Center hang while trying to install Dropbox? 3. How do I properly install Dropbox? All of these questions have been answered and upvoted, but what hasn't been answered are all possible combinations of 1 & 2 and 1 & 3 and 2 & 3. In the limiting case of a question called "Cannot remove Dropbox" I'm for not extending the question into 2 or 3 (although it's inviting to do so) since answers for 2 and 3 already exist.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing exactly what the error message says:

Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

In this case, Ubuntu has nice error messages.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but it just tries to continue the installation of dropbox

Comment: @user3070181 Let it complete the installation. It is a "broken package" so it needs to be fixed. Once it is done installing, just remove it.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is it doesn't install - it just sits there for hours

Comment: @user3070181 Is there a specific place it hangs?

Comment: Yes -  
jeff@cnicht:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up nautilus-dropbox (0.7.1-2) ...

Dropbox is the easiest way to share and store your files online. Want to learn more? Head to http://www.dropbox.com/

Downloading Dropbox... 100%

Comment: It just hangs at the end of the download?

Comment: Yes. It's been like that for 4 hours

Answer (score -1):

Still going!

Is it safe to assume it's not going to install? :)

---

Answers like the above often get deleted very quickly unless you include some sort of answer in the answer, so here are some links that might help.

1. [How do I uninstall Dropbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182416/how-do-i-uninstall-dropbox)
2. Why does the Software Center hang while trying to install Dropbox? And how can I make it stop hanging? -- [Dropbox install stuck at 99%, how do I fix it? (and any dpkg errors)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154671/dropbox-install-stuck-at-99-how-do-i-fix-it-and-any-dpkg-errors)
3. [How to install Dropbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126198/how-to-install-dropbox). There are different answers to this question for different versions of Ubuntu, so select an answer for Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: If you have dpkg errors from trying to install Dropbox, fix them first! (by removing Dropbox) After that, it's not an uncommon problem: [Dropbox install stuck at 99%, how do I fix it? (and any dpkg errors)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154671/dropbox-install-stuck-at-99-how-do-i-fix-it-and-any-dpkg-errors).

Comment: Thanks karel. Fixed it. So frustrating until you know where and how to look :)