# Dropbox erasing itself (in Ubuntu)?

Tags: dropbox, chromebook, crouton

I am a not too Linux savvy so perhaps use a grain of salt,but this seems weird to me... Dropbox seems to be erasing itself from my Ubuntu install (Chromebook - Crouton with xiwi, Ubuntu 16.04.06 xfce). 
Installed it yesterday with no problem then desktop icon disappeared and the command dropbox was not found. Reinstalled it with the following two commands:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf
```

---

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

---

It installed and seemed to run. I clicked on the icon and my whole Linux process froze. When I restarted it from the ChromeOS terminal, the process attempted to start Dropbox and returned this error: 
*xfce4-appfinder: failed to execute: Failed to execute child process "dropbox" (No such file or directory)*
Putting "dropbox" into the Ubuntu terminal yields *bash: Dropbox: command not found* and trying to remove it (using instructions from [How do I uninstall Dropbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182416/how-do-i-uninstall-dropbox)) yields: *Package 'nautilus-dropbox' is not installed, so not removed* and *Package 'dropbox' is not installed, so not removed*

This has happened 3 times now.
Seems weird to me...

Comment: What command do you run to "restarted it from the ChromeOS terminal"? Why do you expect to have a "dropbox" command, when the correct command is `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`? `rm -rf ~/.dropbox-dist` etc removed dropbox from the system, and you've not had nautilus in the first place, so everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

**solved the problem**. Used Synaptic Package Manager to install the package when Dropbox tech support could not solve it. The install from Dropbox must be missing some component, or have a different version of some component that was not compatible with this computer, chromeOS, crouton, ubuntu or xfce version.